# Cómo mostrar un aviso o alerta cuando presiono un botón para generar un pdf?

Tags: laravel, blade, dompdf

bien estoy generando un `PDF` con la librería `DomPDF` desde el `controlador` con `laravel 5.8`

**Controlador**

```
public function downloadPDF($datos){ 

   $pdf = \PDF::loadView('index',[
   'datos' => $datos,
   ]);

   return $pdf->download("nombre.pdf");
}
```

**Botón**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"  href="{{route('downloadPDF')}}">Descargar PDF</a>
```

El `PDF` se genera correctamente, la necesidad es la siguiente:

Como en el elemento `<a>` no estoy agregando `target="_blank"` al presionar el `btn` obviamente se "mantiene" en la misma vista cuando esta cargando el proceso para "generar" el `pdf`,
en este caso el usuario no sabe si el sistema esta haciendo algo (en este caso descargando el pdf).

Entonces al presionar el botón quiero saber como puedo hacer para mostrar un `alerta`,`preload` o algo por el estilo y se mantenga hasta que se descargue el `PDF`.